# Record Audio on Android App as a Service

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-service

I am trying to create an Application that will record Audio during meetings and such, and also allow the user the ability to create annotations / comments while recording.

There are a lot of tutorials on recording basic audio as an activity on the web, but I was wondering if it is possible to make it so that the app will record Audio as a service, thus allowing the user to do other things while recording such as e-mail etc.

I can post additional information if needed to clarify anything.

Looking forward to hear your responses,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

hi dan i think this site help you, 
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html
can you downolad example and use it.